# Want to use * condition in Xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

I want to extract tags in `XML` which contains attribute condition as `name="var"`. But I don't know which element has got this attribute condition so can I use following XQuery:

```
<ab>
    <c name="var">
        <d name ="var">
            <e>
            </e>
        </d>
        <f>
        </f>
    </c>
</ab>
```

XQuery:

```
doc('abc.xml')//ab/*[@name="var"]
```

I have `XML` generated by `CLANG` which has no values for tags but everything is present as attribute only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently select all elements in `abc.xml` which are children of an element called `<ab>` and have the given attribute.

As you want "extract tags in XML which contains" and the document provided I guess you actually want to query all elements within top-level-element `<ab>`, which would be written as

```
doc('abc.xml')/ab//*[@name="var"]
```

and return both element `<c>` and `<d>` with their respective child nodes.

```
<c name="var">
  <d name="var">
    <e/>
  </d>
  <f/>
</c>

<d name="var">
  <e/>
</d>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this must be a dup

```
doc('abc.xml')//*[@name="var"]
```

should work, but may not be particularly efficient, depending on your XQuery processor.